# AWS: add key pair after creating instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm new to AWS.

I created an instance on EC2. It's a Bitnami Wordpress install.

I didn't realize that I needed a key pair, and when I added one after the fact, it does not allow me to connect. I get "Permission denied (publickey)."

Can I disconnect the instance without losing the Bitnami WP install?

Will doing so allow me to add a key pair?

Do I need to create another instance and redo everything?

Comment: Are you trying SSH? For ssh you have to open the Port 22 into the security group then you will be able to connect to the instance

Comment: If it has no keypair at all you will need to delete it and create a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately yes. You have to specify the `keypair` when you launch the instance **unless** the AMI comes with a well known username/password and the SSH daemon accepts both password and key.

In fact, AWS warns you when you proceed to launch an instance without a `keypair`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Won't be the last time I get ahead of myself.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the instance as an ami image.  This will basically save the instance in its current state which includes the bitnami installation.  Then you can create a new instance using this custom ami and add a key pair during the initial configuration.

Comment: Good to know! Unfortunately I already deleted my instanace, but good to have your answer in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you manage your stacks properly there are some values that you can change but there are somethings you can't. Mostly with the IP etc I think? This could be wrong in some situations. This particular one, the link implies will work.

**Obviously if the instance is not already created from a stack in "Cloud Formation" it's not going to help, but you can be more prepared in the future.**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/updating.stacks.walkthrough.html#update.walkthrough.security.group

> To add SSH access to an existing Amazon EC2 instance
>
> 1) Add two additional parameters to the template to pass in the name
>   of an existing Amazon EC2 key pair and SSH location.
>
> 2) Add the KeyName property to the Amazon EC2 instance.
>
> 3) Add port 22 and the SSH location to the ingress rules for the
>   Amazon EC2 security group.
>
> 4) Update the stack, either from the AWS
>   Management Console as explained in Update the Application or by using
>   the AWS command aws cloudformation update-stack.